# How do I find out what my Apple vendor ID is?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm doing some Apple iTunes Connect reporting via the Autoingest tool.  It requires that I not only specify login account info, but also a "vendorid".  I have no clue what our vendor ID might be.  Where can I find such info on Apple's site?

Comment: Developer questions are best suited for Apple’s Developer Forums. Please ask your question there.

Comment: We're going to keep this open and see what kind of answers it draws. We've been [discussing making iTunes connect on-topic](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/what-would-happen-if-we-expanded-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-itunes-connec) for a while, and this looks like a good test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the **Sales and Trends** section, and your vendor ID will be displayed in the upper-left corner next to your developer name. It should start with an 8.

[image: sales & trends]

[image: vendor id]

(Source: [discussions.apple.com thread](https://discussions.apple.com///thread/3308523?start=0&tstart=0))

Comment: This is no longer correct.

Answer (score 15):

This number may be a bit harder to find since Apple re-designed iTunes Connect on Mon, Feb 17th, 2014.

Multiple vendors: If you go into the monthly financial section and have multiple vendors a drop down will show up in the upper left with this number.

If you only have one vendor: Download a monthly financial report. The vendor id is the long number at the beginning of the report name before the first underscore.

Answer (score 12):

With the new iTunesConnect, you don't actually have to download a financial report to get the Vendor ID.

Go to "Sales and Trends", then choose "Reports" from the drop-down menu in the top left.

On the next screen, there'll be a drop-down menu for "Vendor". Your name and ID will be shown there.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the latest version of the Autoingestion script is looking for a 10 digit version of the ID.   If you stick two zero's in front of the number it gives you on the Sales and Trends page that will work...

Comment: This is not the case anymore. My 8 digit id works fine. Adding 2 zeros gives me an error "Please enter a valid vendor number".

Answer (score 1):

**2022 answer:**

In order to get your Vendor ID in App Store Connect

1. Click on Sales and Trends
2. Click on Reports (on the top navigation bar)
3. Vendor # will be in the top left of the screen under your name / business.

Comment: literally tryna contact apple support w/ vendor id because sales and trends page isn't loading....